# Безличное односоставное или двусоставное?

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Тогда ему было 20 лет.
Не могу определить грамматическую основу предложения, но больше склоняюсь к варианту, что оно безличное со сказуемым "было".

Answer (score 3):

***Тогда ему было 20 лет.***

**ОТВЕТ**

**Сказуемое** «было» — простое глагольное, это предикативная основа предложения.

***Было*** — полнозначный глагол (не связка) со значением **существования**.  А что существовало, то есть что является субъектом? Двадцать лет? Нет, это не предмет/субъект, а всего лишь его **признак.** Поэтому мы считаем, что ""двадцать лет" — это не подлежащее, а именно **дополнение в форме В.п.**  Семантическим субъектом состояния является ***он*** в форме Д.п. ***ему***.

**Предложение** односоставное безличное, в структурную схему в **обязательном** порядке входят **два дополнения**: было (что?) двадцать лет, было (кому?) ему.

***Ему*** — грамматическое дополнение и в то же время семантический субъект действия/состояния.

Дополнение "ему" **не входит** в состав сказуемого, но является обязательным структурным элементом в составе предложения. На таких же правах туда **входит прямое дополнение** "двадцать лет".

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

1. Я думаю, что это **безличное предложение**, что можно определить **по словарю.**

**БЫТЬ**, наст. вр. нет (кроме 3 л. ед.: есть; книжн., 3 л. мн.: суть); будь, будьте; был, была, было (с отриц.: не был, не была, не было, не были); буду, будешь; бывший; будучи; нсв. **5. (в наст. вр. с опущением).** Наступать (о времени суток, года и т.п.). (Был) уже вечер. Был девятый день после смерти матери. Будет весна - на душе станет легче. Это (будет) начало Нового года. // **Находиться в каком-л. возрасте; исполняться, отмечаться (о дате со дня рождения, основания, появления кого-, чего-л.).** Сыну (будет) скоро пять. Профессору (было) далеко за шестьдесят. В 2003 г. (будет) трёхсотлетие со дня основания Петербурга

**ИСПОЛНИТЬСЯ**, -нится; св. 1. Осуществиться, выполниться. Желание, обещание исполнилось. **2. кому-чему. Достигнуть определённого предела** (о возрасте, сроке). **Ребёнку исполнился год.** □**БЕЗЛ. Мне исполнилось тридцать лет.** Исполнилось пятьдесят лет со дня окончания войны. <Исполняться, -яется; нсв.

2. Итак, можно записать: ***Тогда ему было (исполнилось) 20 лет.***
   Предложение безличное, если следовать **словарю**, например: *Мне исполнилось тридцать лет.*
3. **Двусоставным** считается предложение: *Ребёнку исполнился год* (согласование в роде и числе с сущ. год).
4. **Другие примеры** из словаря:

В настоящем времени глагол опускается: **Сейчас** ему 20 лет. Сыну (будет) **скоро** пять. Профессору (**было**) далеко за шестьдесят.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Если разбирать предложение с точки зрения **семантики,** а не грамматики, то ***ему*** — это семантический субъект действия/состояния в форме Д.п (***он***), а ***двадцать лет*** — это признак субъекта (его возраст).

Грамматический разбор: ***было*** — сказуемое в односоставном предложении;
***двадцать лет*** — дополнение (было сколько лет?), ***ему*** — дополнение (было кому?). Сочетание ***ему было*** является характерным **признаком** безличного предложения.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Тогда ему было 20 лет.*** Не могу определить грамматическую основу предложения, но больше склоняюсь к варианту, что оно безличное…

Есть и такая точка зрения (у некоторых лингвистов).

Есть и другая.

**В.А. Добромыслов и Д.Э. Розенталь. «Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания». М., 1958**:

> ***Вопрос***. Как произвести синтаксический разбор предложения
> ***Мне сорок лет***?
>
> ***Ответ***.  Предложение *Мне сорок лет* является **двусоставным**, неполным. Подлежащее в нём выражено сочетанием ***сорок лет***.
> Сказуемое восполняется из смысла самой фразы (например,
> *исполнилось*). В прошедшем времени: *Мне **было** сорок лет*; в будущем: *Мне **будет** сорок лет*. Ср. *Сорок лет мне **было** в
> феврале*, *Сорок лет мне **будет** в феврале*, где ***было, будет***
> не связка, а полнозначный глагол («исполнилось», «сравнялось»,
> «исполнится» и т.д.). ***Мне*** – дополнение, входящее в состав
> сказуемого данного предложения.

См.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ПРОДОЛЖЕНИЕ.**

Такой подход к классификации подобных рассматриваемому предложений и выделению в их составе в качестве подлежащего количественно-именного сочетания был не только в пятидесятых годах прошлого века. Зафиксирован он и в учебниках, по которым училось большинство сегодняшних учителей.

**Из учебника 1989 года для пед. институтов под ред. Л.Ю. Максимова  (раздел «Синтаксис» написан Ширяевым Е.Н.):**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Выше я написал, что  и есть и другая точка зрения (у некоторых лингвистов) на классификацию предложений типа ***Ему было двадцать лет***. Такие предложения они считают безличными.

Ни глагол ***быть***, ни глагол ***исполниться*** не являются переходными и не могут иметь в русском языке прямого дополнения в винительном падеже. А уж постфикс «-***ся***» в возвратных глаголах вообще в трудных случаях используется как маркер для опознавания именно **именительного** падежа в предложениях в сочетаемых с этими глаголами словах.

Сказанное относится и к предложению ***Ему было двадцать лет***: количественно-именное сочетание ***двадцать лет*** стоит в нём в **именительном** падеже (НИКАК НЕ ВИНИТЕЛЬНОМ !) и является (в случае отнесения этого предложения к безличным!) **именной частью составного именного сказуемого**.

См. пример из диссертации Матвеевой О.И. «**Семантика и функционирование русских нумеративных предложений**»:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расшифровывается условное обозначение **N 3 — (cop) Num card / ord 1 (N 1 / 2)** в этом примере так:

N 3  — существительное или местоимение в дательном падеже;

Num card / ord 1 — количественное или порядковое числительное в именительном падеже;

N 1 / 2 — существительное в **именительном** или родительном падеже.

**cop** — связка (НЕ ЗНАМЕНАТЕЛЬНЫЙ ГЛАГОЛ !).

---

Ну а как разбирают эти предложения в сегодняшних школах – думаю, единой точки зрения у учителей нет. Так же, как нет и единого взгляда на на формант «-ть» в начальной форме глаголов и на многое другое…

Comment: Мне очень понравился ваш ответ, голосую за него: он вполне логичен и к тому же обоснован. Именно так и должно разбираться данное предложение. С "мне" не совсем согласен, для меня это обычное дополнение.

Comment: @Aigy: _С "мне" не совсем согласен, для меня это обычное дополнение._ === Это и есть обычное дополнение. См. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1547

Answer (score 1):

**Двусоставное**. Двадцать лет (подлежащее), было (сказуемое).

---

**Односоставным** данное предложение не может быть по своей сути. Глагол "быть" связан с подлежащим, выраженным количественно-именным сочетанием, которое включает в себя основную информацию этого предложения. "Быть" и является носителем "новой" информацией о подлежащем, утверждая, что кто-то находится (существует) в "состоянии n-го количества лет".

---

Некоторые участники предлагают абсурдные версии, ставя на роль подлежащего
неведомое дополнение, которое стоит якобы в винительном падеже. Это совершенно лишено логики, поскольку глагол "быть" не может управлять винительным падежом, а вот с именительным падежом глагол "быть" прекрасно сочетается.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, какие вопросы нужно задать при разборе предложения.

Comment: @Sharon Поясните свой вопрос: он непонятен.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Ну, обычные вопросы при разборе такие: (что?) двадцать лет, (что делало?) было. Но они звучат странно. И еще интересно, что в настоящем времени: Ему двадцать лет. Здесь глагола вообще нет. А какой тогда вид предложения? Из-за этого возникают трудности при определении предикативной основы, а также можно подумать, что это безличное предложение. Например: Ему было( сколько лет?).  Или: это составное именное сказуемое. Надо доказать, что эти варианты некорректны, так как это неочевидно.

Comment: Замечу только, что некоторые "абсурдные" участники заимствовали свой ответ из словаря. К сожалению, в исправленном ответе по-прежнему нет никаких ссылок на источники, как то: словари, учебники по грамматике и т.д.  И это в то время как "неправильные" участники постоянно пользуются материалами из вузовского учебника по современному синтаксису.

Answer (score 1):

Было - сказуемое, с этим нет вопросов.
Но дальше есть сложности.
Я думаю, что все реверсивные конструкции, когда существительное/числительное и тп идет после сказуемого - это дополнения, а не подлежащие, и падеж винительный, а не именительный.

Сколько было котов? Было сорок котов, было много котов и тп.

Либо, числительное является подлежащим, а котов - дополнением. Хотя меня смущает расположение подлежащего после сказуемого.

Поэтому сказуемое - было, мне - дополнение входящее в состав сказуемого, сорок лет - просто дополнение в винительном падеже.

Безличное, с одной стороны, однако личное дополнение должно быть. Так что насколько безличное вопрос дискуссионный, я бы назвал такие предложения "неопределенно-личными", когда о личности говорят отстраненно: Ване было 10 лет ~ Ваня был десятилетний. Безличное же - это самодостаточное предложение, где глагол в инфинитиве, без дополнение, или сочетающийся с ОНО - расцвело, (мне) нужно бежать и т.д. В неопределенно-личном дополнение сказуемого не отбрасывается.

Так что: неопределенно-личное, односоставное, с личным дополнением входящим в состав сказуемого и просто дополнением, не входящим в состав сказуемого.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148046/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

**Мои комментарии для участника @Ajgy**

**Количественные оборот в прошедшем времени сочетается** со ср.родом или мн. числом, и здесь нет информации о статусе предложения. Поэтому я ориентируюсь **на СЛОВАРЬ,** где указаны все значения глагола "быть" и все формы времени для предложений со значением возраста. А также прямо сказано, что такой тип предложений относится **к БЕЗЛИЧНЫМ**. В этом случае можно задать **естественный вопрос**: было сколько лет? Это дополнение, указание на возраст. Поэтому давайте не указывать на корректность ответа, это НЕ ПО ПРАВИЛАМ форума. Вы уже обозначили свое мнение в ответе. Вот туда и добавьте этот материал. –
Sharon

**Там достаточно места, а развернутые комментарии запрещены.** Я не буду больше отвечать в комментариях. Мой ответ вы можете только уточнить или улучшить, а вы критикуете. Я в своих комментариях не назвала ваш ответ неправильным, а всего лишь уточнила его. Давайте будем цивилизованными и будем доказывать свою правоту по существующим правилам. –
Sharon

**От минусовки моего ответа** ваш ответ не будет более убедительным. Это всего лишь ваше мнение, не подкрепленное источниками. Причем в удивительно краткой форме, безо всякого обоснования. А ведь вопрос отнюдь не самый простой, желательно было доказать, что это не безличное предложение. –
Sharon

**Грамматика в каждом языке своя**, не стоит сравнивать. А вопрос лучше задать на форуме. Конечно, у меня есть определенное мнение, но я предпочитаю не высказывать свои мнения без ссылок на авторитетный источник. А то себе дороже) Примеры с явным подлежащим: Двадцать лет срок немалый. Двадцать лет было очень большим сроком. Из словаря: Сыну (будет) скоро пять. Ей (сейчас) двадцать лет. Структура вроде бы одинаковая. Пропуск сказуемого в настоящем времени не влиет на вид предложения. –
Sharon

**Так какие у вас проблемы, зачем вы меня спрашиваете?** Вы нашли ответ у специалистов? Прекрасно! **Добавьте ссылку в свой ответ**, хотя бы как-то поясните свою точку зрения. Меня не надо убеждать, это обществу нужен ваш развернутый ответ. **В словаре написано**: Мне исполнилось (= было) тридцать лет. Это безличное предложение, Глагол "быть" в значении №5 (исполниться, находиться в возрасте). Винительный падеж для числительного? Например: Их было пятеро (пять человек). Это какой падеж, неужели И.п.? И давайте не будем все это обсуждать в комментариях, это не по правилам. Их все равно отправят в чат. –
Sharon

**А "их" – дополнение?** Оригинальный разбор. Кстати, **позиция слов** в предложениях со значением количества или бытия важна (тот самый пресловутый **дискуссионный вопрос** в лингвистике, может, слышали). Зачем вы **меняете порядок слов** под свою модель? И еще раз вас прошу, давайте не будем обсуждать важную тему в частном порядке. Я больше писать ничего не буду, особенно обсуждать абсурд в вашем толковании. Да и времени у меня на это больше нет. До свидания, спасибо за беседу.

**МОЙ КОММЕНТАРИЙ ко всем трем решениям**

Чудесно! Весь "абсурд" (**словарь, собственное мнение, учебное пособие 1958 года**) собран в одной теме. А фраза ведь известная, почти устойчивый оборот речи. Поэтому **не хватает еще двух ответов,** при этом желательны не **собственные суждения** (что и с чем прекрасно сочетается), а **ссылки** на авторитетные источники):

(1) Как делается разбор **в современной школе.**

(2) Что говорится в современных учебниках **по грамматике**, что думают **современные лингвисты** и т.д.

P.S. Современная **монография о БЕЗЛИЧНЫХ предложениях** нашлась в моей библиотеке (2019 год, 2-е издание), но материал не адаптирован для учебных целей и требует времени для изучения и понимания. Постараюсь это время найти и немного **освежить 1958 год.** Увы, поезд с названием ***"грамматика-экспресс"*** давно уже ушел из этих мест.

А вот **школьная программа** остается под вопросом: как там-То правильно отвечать?

Comment: «_**Чудесно! Весь "абсурд" собран в одной теме. А фраза ведь известная, почти устойчивый оборот речи. Поэтому не хватает еще двух ответов, при этом желательны не собственные суждения (что и с чем прекрасно сочетается), а ссылки на авторитетные источники)**_». === По-моему, я, В ОТЛИЧИЕ от Вас, привёл весьма авторитетный источник.  Вы же не привели НИ ОДНОГО. И если скажете, что этим _авторитетным_ источником  в Вашем ответе  считается словарь Кузнецова, я напомню Вам Ваше, сказанное  пару лет назад, мнение о словаристах.

Comment: Не надо дискуссий,надоели пустые разговоры ни о чем. Я привела  словарь (на сайте Грамота.ру), вы привели учебник середины прошлого века. Хотелось бы что-нибудь поновее, знаете ли. А с вами я вообще незнакома, вы на форуме всего 3 месяца. Если были здесь раньше, то мне это неизвестно.

Comment: В вашем источники несовременный подход к грамматике. В настоящее время модель предложения не ДОМЫСЛИВАЮТ, а работают именно с этой конкретной моделью.  Порядок слов и тот важен. И хорошо было бы, чтобы выбранный вариант подходил ко всем временам (настоящее, прошедшее, будущее), а то получается на каждое время своя модель.

Comment: «_**В вашем источники несовременный подход к грамматике. В настоящее время модель предложения не ДОМЫСЛИВАЮТ, а работают именно с этой конкретной моделью. Порядок слов и тот важен. И хорошо было бы, чтобы выбранный вариант подходил ко всем временам (настоящее, прошедшее, будущее), а то получается на каждое время своя модель.**_  === Всего того, что Вы требуете от чужих ответов, **в своих ответах Вы не приводите.** И почему Вы решили, что разбор, приведённый когда-то Розенталем с Добромысловым не подходит к «настоящему, прошедшему, будущему», думаю, Вы и сами не сможете объяснить.

Comment: Думаю, что могу, но не буду. Зачем мне это надо? Бессмысленная трата времени: вы все равно ничего не поймете, да и зачем я буду о вас заботиться. Так что до свидания, Слава. Пора мне отдохнуть от моих критиков, а то их стало уж очень много. Работать нормально все равно не дадут. Я их притягиваю, как магнит железные опилки.

Comment: @Sharon, а в pdf варианте у вас нет этого материала?

Comment: В этой теме я ориентируюсь на книгу В..И.Казарина  "Простое предложение в аспекте структурно- семантического подхода", 2-е изд., 2019 год  .https://www.labirint.ru/books/664753/

Comment: В этой теме разногласия возникли по терминологии.  Раньше термин  "состав сказуемого" использовался при обозначении минимальной структурной модели предложений (сказуемое + дополнение, «было ему») ,  то есть включал обязательное дополнение.  А сейчас он в таком понимании не используется, да и вообще применяется редко. (К примеру, в теме «тире между подлежащим и сказуемым» можно сказать о составе подлежащего и сказуемого, то есть главный член + все распространители.) Сейчас мы имеем в виду то, что непосредственно входит в состав сказуемого (простого или составного).

Comment: Кустова считает, что «ему» — это необходимый структурный элемент СКАЗУЕМОГО в безличном предложении. Что касается числового оборота «20 лет» (прямое дополнение В.п. или подлежащее И.п.), то надо найти в грамматике точное описание структурной модели этого ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ (было что? было ему?) .  Это уже касается предикативной основы. Я склоняюсь к варианту безличного предложения, а не двусоставного. Кстати, этот вариант был предложен автором вопроса.