# Каким членом предложения является слово "одиннадцать" в данном предложении: Было одиннадцать, и никто не думал о сне?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, подлежащее

Сначала я думал, что это подлежащее, но слово "было" прибавило сомнений.  Информация в интернете разнится. Помогите,  пожалуйста!

Comment: По официальным нормам это подлежащее, прикол в том, что подлежащее отвечает на вопрос кто/что, а не сколько, а тут сколько. Сколько вас было? Нас было двое. - тоже подлежащее

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474860/%d0%91%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5

Answer (score 0):

```
13. Подвод в обозе было около двадцати (Чехов). // Сколько ?
14. Сорок лет ему будет ещё не скоро (Чехов). // Что ?
```

Подлежащее - числительное. [Ссылка](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/42-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_uprazhneniya/stages/885-12_podlezhaschee.html)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! Я так и думал :)